# Jquery UI Resizable Aspect Ratio setting conditional on type of contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

I am building an app where I have different kinds of divs going onto the page. Some are filled with an `<img>` and some with a `<span>`. All divs have a class called draggable on them. I make all div's with the draggable class resizable by doing this:

```
        $( '.draggable' ).resizable({
            maxWidth: 500,
            aspectRatio: false,
            containment: 'parent', 
            start: function() {
                last_element = $(this);
            },
            resize: function() {
                $(this).children('img').css('width',$(this).css('width'));
                $(this).children('img').css('height',$(this).css('height'));
            },
            stop: function() {
                updateDiv($(this).attr('id'));
            }
        });
```

Is there any way to make the `aspectRatio` value dependent on the contents of div? I tried doing this:

```
aspectRatio: ($(this).children('img').length ? true : false),
```

I would like it so that textboxes (those divs with spans in them) can be resized with aspectratio = false, but image boxes (those divs with imgs in them) have aspectratio = true.

I know I can setup two different classes (.draggable and .draggable_img) but instead of doing that I'm just wondering if there is something simple I can do without having redundant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a context issue. `$(this)` is referencing `window` instead of the `.draggable` element at that level. What you could do is something like this. Once you do that your logic for setting true/false is fine.

```
$('.draggable').each(function() {

    $(this).resizable({
        maxWidth: 500,
        aspectRatio: ($(this).children('img').length ? true : false),
        containment: 'parent',
        start: function() {
            //last_element = $(this);
        },
        resize: function() {
            //$(this).children('img').css('width',$(this).css('width'));
            //$(this).children('img').css('height',$(this).css('height'));
        },
        stop: function() {
            //updateDiv($(this).attr('id'));
        }
    });
});​
```

[***Check out this fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/8BEEx/1/).